# Safari 5 cookies DB location

Tags: windows-7, safari, safari-5

I am trying to locate Safari 5 cookies SQLite DB file location under Windows 7, but can't find it under the path \AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari\

Can someone please help and tell me where I can locate this file?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1):

Try here:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Safari\Cookies
```

File I found there is `cookies.binarycookies`, but I have no suggestions as to what program to open it with.